# Kafka max throughput in messages per Second

Tags: apache-kafka, rhel

What is the max throughput of Kafka in messages per second.

we wanted to check what is the theoretical max throughput that could be reached. in messages per second

we intend to use Apache Kafka version - 2.7.x and OS is RHEL 7.9

the physical machines with 125G memory and 32 Core per machine

links - https://aiven.io/blog/benchmarking-kafka-write-throughput-performance-2019-update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max throughput is always going to be measured without network overhead (a local consumer/producer), and have no acks (message not durably or reliably written to disk), and no TLS encryption.

Neither are useful tests or metrics to gather.

Run your own benchmarking using performance test CLI commands included with Kafka, or external tools like Gatling/JMeter

Kafka brokers are not RAM intensive, so each machine doesn't require 125G of memory. The disk speed and partitioning scheme will matter more, e.g. 7200 RPM w/ XFS formatted.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/deployment.html

Comment: lets say we not have network overhead and with my spec , in that case can we works with 50K messages per secc ?

Comment: Maybe. Depends on your JVM vendor and settings, hardware profile, etc. Benchmark it